# Getting "page not found" error while trying to go back to the previous page after successful deletion using DeleteView in django

Tags: python, django, web

So I'm deleting an object of a model using DeleteView and redirecting to homePage after successful deletion, works fine. But the problem is when I try to get back to the previous page after deletion(using the left arrow button in the browser). I get "page not found" error which makes total sense because I'm trying to get back to the deletion page of an object which no longer exist. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using class-based (generic) views to delete, you can use `reverse_lazy` to redirect after delete. In case you are using functional views, you can `redirect` after the successful deletion of the object from the Database.

Comment: I'm using success_url=reverse_lazy() for redirecting

Comment: if you using reverse lazy to redirect, then what is the point of going back to the page. If so, the server should respond with 404 as the post does not exist anymore.

Comment: I understand. My question is, is it ideal to get a 404 error in this case?

Comment: yeah if you query the database and get nothing, the server should return a 404 not found an error. you can use `get_object_or_404` to specifically send a 404.